# Automating a SQL query

Tags: sql, excel

i am very new to SQL and my employer who uses SQL server 2005 would like to have a daily query, which we run for a specific report, automated and emailed to various recipients in an excel format using a template they already have on file. Can i please get some help on how i can make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SQL Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880) to schedule T-SQL jobs in SQL Server.

Comment: hi and thanks for help, will i be able to have it emailed directly in an excel format?

Comment: You can check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185885/send-data-via-email-in-t-sql). I would just work with CSV and not "real" Excel.

Comment: If you are using SQLServer you may be able to automate it, if it is Express you won't probably. You could create a view on the server and import into excel and manage the email through vba if you are using express instead